# Why can Perspective Warp cause my Mac to run out of application memory?

Tags: macos, memory, adobe-photoshop

I'm running Adobe Photoshop CC on a Mac with 32GB RAM. I have no performance issues other than Perspective Warp. Sometimes it works immediately, sometimes after a few seconds (while I wait for the revolving rainbow wheel to stop spinning) but it seems to take longer each time I use it within a session - eventually generating an 'out of application memory' message and freezing Photoshop. Restarting the Mac usually resets the function.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 3):

You don’t actually specify what model of Mac you have, nor what you mean by *within a session*.

However, the perspective warp function is a rather CPU and GPU intensive task. How long it takes will depend on a number of factors, such as the complexity and size of the files you’re working with, the amount of VRAM your GPU has access to, and so on.

Also, if you’re trying to use the perspective warp function repeatedly during relatively short periods of time, you may find that your system starts heating up beyond acceptable limits and the CPU and/or GPU become throttled in order to protect them from damage.

Finally, while you do seem to have a good amount of RAM (32GB is nothing to be sneezed at), the perspective warp feature is actually more demanding of the GPU and the amount of VRAM it has access to. So you may find that’s the cause of your memory issues, especially if you’re using perspective warp repeatedly within short periods.

Comment: Most of our photoshop Mac run 8 GB of ram total on the Mac and run very fast with 2 GB RAM to PS on 2017 model iMac. Unless you have a specific operation and haven’t tuned photoshop settings for your file types and specific needs,  throwing ram at that app is usually counterproductive.

Comment: Great answer as to precisely _why_ this is CPU bound and also taxing of the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Tuning Photoshop to cover all the possibilities would take most of a one semester course for Mac, but you might be able to make great progress by watching your efficiency in the app before and during the operation you see causing a slow down.

- https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/optimize-photoshop-cc-performance.html

Don’t try to change lots of things in the article all at once, instead make one or two changes and then test / document your results. Since you mention that it gets slower and slower over time, focus on the history state controls and the part that talks about purge.

Start with giving Photoshop 1/4 of total RAM up to 6 GB max (if all you ever really want to do is photoshop) and then watch efficiency per window. If you see efficiency go down, experiment with bumping up the RAM reservation as needed. **Saving RAM for the macOS usually is a winning decision** - so take photoshop down to 1  GB if you can based on efficiency of your documents remaining high.

Most times when I find Photoshop slow is due to someone giving all / too much RAM to this one app, starving everything else on the Mac access to that resource.

Comment: That last sentence is worth more than just the one vote I can give. :) If only users understood this!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your really helpful and timely responses. Together, you have helped me to find a solution. I worked through the Adobe help page link that Bmike gave me and eventually came to a section called 'Purge memory', giving me the path in Photoshop CC: Edit>Purge. This selection produced a pop-up menu, the last option being 'Video Cache. Noting Monomeeth's point about VRAM, I click on Video Cache. Problem solved - no more delays! Fantastic!